# Azure AD Multi-tennat Error: Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I created an MVC5 app with Visual Studio 2015 specifying Work/School accounts and multi-tennant.

The code is unchanged from what the VS2015 template created.

I am able to login as a user of the primary domain/tennant.

As a test I created a new AAD and created a user. When I attempt to login with this user I get Error: Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. We received a bad request.

The request is being made to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common which seems correct for mulit-tennant auth.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "common" is the correct endpoint. Is the user from the second tenant a native user, that is to say of the form user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com, or is it a Microsoft Account or a guest user from a different tenant? Also, when you created the app did you turn on read access to the directory? If you did, then only tenant admins will initially be able to access the app from another tenant

Comment: it is a native user. I did have read access on. I tried both setting the user to global admin and also turning off read access on the application. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry you are having a bad experience here. We might need to gather some more data, like fiddler traces and such. If you want to start an email thread with me, hit me via http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/contact/ and I will reply via email.

Comment: I went to create a fiddler trace and now it's working. I guess it just took some time for the changes to propogate.  Is there any good doc on this, ie the requirements for a tenant admin, etc?  If you put your info as an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Also, what  will happen if my tenant has MS account users? Will I get the MS Live tenant id rather than the Azure AD tenant id?